# The bases for the set of all functions f:[0,1]→[0,1]

Tags: calculus, general-topology, proof-verification, proof-writing

Let $X = [0, 1]^{[0,1]}$, the set of all functions $f : [0, 1] \rightarrow [0, 1]$. Given a subset $A \subseteq [0, 1]$, let $U_A = \{ f \in X : f(x) = 0 \forall x \in A \}$ .
Show that $B := \{U_A : A \subseteq [0, 1] \}$ is a basis for a topology on X.

My attempt at the solution: Since X is the collection of all functions that take $[0,1] \rightarrow [0,1]$ then $\forall f \in X \exists x \in [0,1]$ s.t f(x) = 0. Since $\mathcal{B}$ is exactly a collection of sets that go to 0 at some point in [0,1], it covers all of X. Now for the second property of the bases, Let $U_A$ and $U_B$ be two sets belonging to $\mathcal{B}$ with a non-empty intersection. Let $B' = U_A \cap U_B$ then $B'$ is also a set of functions f s.t f(x) = 0 $\forall x \in A \cap B$ and since $A \cap B \subseteq [0,1]. $ We have that $B' \subseteq U_A \cap U_B$ belongs to $\mathcal{B}$ this satisfies the second property of being a bases. Hence, $\mathcal{B}$ is a bases on X.
Does this proof look okay and is it clear enough ?

Comment: "Since X is the collection of all functions that take $[0,1] \rightarrow [0,1]$ then $\forall f \in X \exists x \in [0,1]$ s.t f(x) = 0."

That's not true at all -- function that's constantly equal 1 is in $X$, but doesn't satisfy that statement.

Comment: I was assuming that the functions go to every point in [0,1], I see how that was a silly assumption to make, but then how do we show that $\mathcal{B}$ covers all of X.

Comment: Well, $U_\emptyset = X$.

Comment: The title makes little sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply note that $U_\emptyset = X$, and $U_{A} \cap U_B = U_{A \cup B}$, so the union is $X$ and the set is even closed under intersections.